# PyQt5. Выбор GroupBox по сигналу от кнопки

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

В продолжение [Изменение размеров фреймов во вкладке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309815), начал разбираться с обработкой сигналов.

Идея состоит в том что при нажатии на кнопку Task1 - фрейм Welcoмe (`class Welcome(QGroupBox)`) меняется на фрейм Task1 (`class Task1(QGroupBox)`), Task2 -> фрейм Task2 и т.д.

Во время обработки сигналов от кнопок столкнулся с проблемами поэтому кнопки перенес в класс `Tab1`.
Когда-то я уже сталкивался с подобной проблемой в Tkinter и в качестве решения можно было использовать метод `destroy`, очевидно, что данный метод тут работать не будет (и не работает).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout,
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QApplication,
    QTabWidget, QPushButton, QGroupBox, QLabel
)

MAIN_APP_HEIGHT = 400
MAIN_APP_WIDTH = 700


class Tab1(QWidget):
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)

    self.cucm_tasks = Welcome()

    self.button_task1 = QPushButton("Task1")
    self.button_task1.clicked.connect(self.change_task)
    self.button_task2 = QPushButton("Task2")
    self.button_task2.clicked.connect(self.change_task)

    self.widgit_box = QVBoxLayout()
    self.widgit_box.addWidget(self.button_task1)
    self.widgit_box.addWidget(self.button_task2)
    self.widgit_box.addStretch(1)

    self.task_box = QGroupBox()
    self.task_box.setTitle("&Tasks")
    self.task_box.setLayout(self.widgit_box)

    self.grid_layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
    self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.task_box, stretch=1)
    self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.cucm_tasks, stretch=5)

@pyqtSlot()
def change_task(self):

    action = self.sender()
    print(action.text())
    self.cucm_tasks.destroy()  # Не работает, хотя и ошибку не кидает.
    if action.text() == "Task1":
        self.cucm_tasks = Task1()
    elif action.text() == "Task2":
        self.cucm_tasks = Task2()
    self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.cucm_tasks, stretch=5)


class Task1(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Task1, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTitle("&Task1")
        pass


class Task2(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Task2, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTitle("&Task2")
        pass


class Welcome(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Welcome, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setTitle("&Welcome")
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(
            QLabel("<h1>Welcome</h1>"), 0, 0, Qt.AlignCenter)


class MainApplication(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.resize(MAIN_APP_WIDTH, MAIN_APP_HEIGHT)
        self.setWindowTitle("App")

        tab1 = Tab1()

        self.main_tabs = QTabWidget()
        self.main_tabs.addTab(tab1, "Tab 1")
        self.main_tabs.addTab(QLabel('Hello world'), "Tab 2")

        grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        grid_layout.addWidget(self.main_tabs)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainApplication()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Вы хотите при клике сдвигать Task* на первый индекс? Или удалять Welcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо `destroy` можно использовать [deleteLater](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater)

```
    @pyqtSlot()
    def change_task(self):
        action = self.sender()
        print(action.text())

        self.cucm_tasks.deleteLater()

        if action.text() == "Task1":
            self.cucm_tasks = Task1()
        elif action.text() == "Task2":
            self.cucm_tasks = Task2()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.cucm_tasks, stretch=5)
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]